# FundMe contract doesn't deploy in my mainnet-fork-dev network in Brownie + Alchemy

Tags: python, solidity, ganache, web3py, alchemy

I've been learning Solidity on the Free Code Camp 16 hour [course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=26s) -
and stuck with the following problem:

1. I created fork of Ethereum Mainnet in Brownie using Alchemy:

> brownie networks add development mainnet-fork-dev cmd=ganache-cli
> host=http://127.0.0.1
> fork=https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/$MY_WEB3_ALCHEMY_PROJECT_ID
> accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=8545

2. Run deploy.py:

```bash
brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network mainnet-fork-dev
```

```py
from brownie import FundMe, MockV3Aggregator, network, config
from scripts.helpful_scripts import (
    get_account, 
    deploy_mocks, 
    LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS
)
from web3 import Web3

def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()

    # if we are on rinkbey so on - use associated address
    # otherwise deploy moks

    if network.show_active() not in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS: 
        price_feed_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["eth_usd_price_feed"]
    else:
        # Deploy fake get price function is the network is fake like Ganeche  
        deploy_mocks()
        price_feed_address = MockV3Aggregator[-1].address

    fund_me = FundMe.deploy(
        price_feed_address,
        {"from": account}, 
        publish_source = config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("verify"),
    )
    
    print(f'\n\n')
    print(f'Active network is {network.show_active()}')
    print(f'Price_feed_address is {price_feed_address}')
    print(f'From account is {account}')
    print(f'Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}')
    print(f'\n\n')

    return fund_me

def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```

3. Terminal gives me:

Running **scripts/deploy.py::main**...
Transaction sent:

```
0x439c0b1aa486c393d04b5b5b329da17d344b9cad751e25ff222b7e18be383021
Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 6721975   Nonce: 0
FundMe.constructor confirmed   Block: 1   Gas used: 405741 (6.04%)
FundMe deployed at: 0x9abEBCe93172DDBA444312C93d0c88372EbA5B31
```

But the contract doesn’t deploy, when I try to call `FundMe[-1]` - the array is empty.

And in the deployments folder, I don’t see ChainId of my mainnet-fork-dev

In Ganache I see this transaction, but it seems like it's not signed ... (I'm not sure, I'm super new in Blockchain)

[image]

How can I fix that?

get_account() and deploy_mocks():

```py
from brownie import network, config, accounts, MockV3Aggregator
from web3 import Web3

FORKED_LOCAL_ENVIRONMENTS = ["mainnet-fork", "mainnet-fork-dev"]
LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS = ["development", "ganache-local"]

DECIMALS = 8
STARTING_PRICE = 200000000000


def get_account():
    if (
        network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS
        or network.show_active() in FORKED_LOCAL_ENVIRONMENTS
    ):
        return accounts[0]
    else:
        return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])


def deploy_mocks():
    print(f"The active network is {network.show_active()}")
    print("Deploying Mocks...")
    if len(MockV3Aggregator) <= 0:
        MockV3Aggregator.deploy(DECIMALS, STARTING_PRICE, {"from": get_account()})
    print("Mocks Deployed!")
```

Comment: can you post ` get_account, 
    deploy_mock, ` functions as well. your current script seems correct

Comment: I added, but everything is working correctly on Rinkeby and Ganache-CLI, it doesn't work only on my fork of the Ethereum network I created in Brownie, I suppose something wrong with the settings of Ganache or Brownie?

Comment: Finally, I got what the problem was!! You have to set Fork setting ON in Ganache, and next try to use Terminal, if you don't click Fork, even if you add a network with the setting "fork" - it won't work and will create blockchain only with 1 block...  maybe it will help someone like me

Comment: @JoshuaWitt Please post that as an answer instead of a comment (and accept it), so that future readers know it was the solution you found to the your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and I solved this issue by adding `"gas_price": "60 gwei"` when deploying your contract, so your code show like this:

```
from brownie import FundMe, MockV3Aggregator, network, config
from scripts.helpful_scripts import (
    get_account, 
    deploy_mocks, 
    LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS
)
from web3 import Web3

def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()

    # if we are on rinkbey so on - use associated address
    # otherwise deploy moks

    if network.show_active() not in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS: 
        price_feed_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["eth_usd_price_feed"]
    else:
        # Deploy fake get price function is the network is fake like Ganeche  
        deploy_mocks()
        price_feed_address = MockV3Aggregator[-1].address

    fund_me = FundMe.deploy(
        price_feed_address,
        {"from": account,
        "gas_price": "60 gwei"
    }, 
        publish_source = config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("verify"),
    )
    
    print(f'\n\n')
    print(f'Active network is {network.show_active()}')
    print(f'Price_feed_address is {price_feed_address}')
    print(f'From account is {account}')
    print(f'Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}')
    print(f'\n\n')
```

You can also add these:

```
from brownie.network import gas_price
from brownie.network.gas.strategies import LinearScalingStrategy

gas_strategy = LinearScalingStrategy("60 gwei", "70 gwei", 1.1)

gas_price(gas_strategy)
```

and in your smart contract do this:

```
fund_me = FundMe.deploy(
        price_feed_address,
        {"from": account,
        "gas_price": gas_price#// here i add gas_price
    }, 
        publish_source = config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("verify"),
    )
```